# Ajax Call not updating DIV in firefox. Working fine in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am sending chat message, and receiving them in particular div.. All read and write with ajax. Everything works fine in Chrome, but in firefox, it does not shows...

Here is my code :-

```
var xmlhttp = false;

function read_message() {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById("chatBox").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET",'http://<?php echo $domain; ?>/m.php?id='+<?php echo $id; ?>,true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","text/html");
    xmlhttp.send();
}

 $(document).ready(function(){
     setInterval("read_message()", 800);
 });
```

$domain is define in Header page and it is Same domain, where file is running... i.e,

if my chat page is in localhost than $domain is also localhost..
I am aware of same origin policy of ajax, but **is this problem due to** using `http://`.

I cannot leave `http://` part as i am using url-rewriting and there my url is something like `http://localhost/chat/user/anonymous` so, if i use only `m.php?id=1` than it tries to fetch page from 
`http://localhost/chat/user/m.php` which obviously doesnot exist... it exist in `http://localhost/m.php`

if above mentioned point is error, is there any way that we can solve it, or any other better help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Use `/m.php?id=1` instead

Comment: Could you post the actual JavaScript that runs in your browser? Posting your (incomplete) server-side code makes the problem more difficult to diagnose.

Comment: Have you ever heard about relative urls?

Comment: @AstDerek Updated my code with /m.php still not working in firefox..

Comment: @apsillers except write_message function of xmlhttp2 there is nothing else in page. i have updated my code with interval function that i am using..
thanks

Comment: @johnsmith Sorry, I meant post that actual script that is sent to the client by the server (i.e., what you see when you "View Source" in your browser). You've posted the PHP code that *generates* that JavaScript, but not the JavaScript itself. (Most of your code has no PHP, obviously, but you *are* using it in the one spot that you've identified as particularly troubling.)

Comment: @epascarello yes, but /m.php?id=1 also does not return content in firefox but it does return content in chrome :(

Comment: @apsillers no .. this is not php generated code, this is static javascript code written in page and available to all... also.. when i view in web-console of firefox.. sometimes it shows content in responsebody and sometimes it don't but in div, it never shows..

Comment: I didn't pay too much attention before. If you are using jQuery, use `$.ajax`

Comment: @AstDerek is that the only solution :(

Comment: @johnsmith `'http://<?php echo $domain; ?>/m.php?id='+<?php echo $id; ?>` is PHP. I was simply asking for you to post the JavaScript code (or, really, just the URL, inline with the JS) that the PHP code generates when it runs. I wanted to see the JavaScript file that runs in the client *after* all PHP processing has been completed on the client. What you have posted here is the PHP code *before* the server processes it. Posting the actual JavaScript code with *no PHP whatsoever* (i.e., post the resulting response) would make your code easier to diagnose.

Comment: Since you're loading jQuery anyways, why not let it do the cross-browser heavy lifting ? ( with the `$.ajax()` call

Comment: @apsillers oh m sorry! this is the line..                             `xmlhttp.open("GET",'/m.php?id='+3,true);` i have removed $domain part

Comment: Also: any chance this code will run twice in rapid succession? If a second request fired before the first request resolved, `xmlhttp.responseText` in your `onreadystatechange` listener would point to the `responseText` of the second, unresolved request when the listener for the first request fired. This is because you only use a single global `xmlhttp` variable that is shared for all requests.

Comment: @apsillers oh my god! bro you are the saviour... time was problem.. i made it 2 sec and it runs fine...  w00t thanks bro...:)

Comment: @apsillers bro please post it as answer so that i can accept it. Thanks bro thanks a lot once again :)

Comment: Your code is still wrong then, it will fail with higher latency

Comment: @AstDerek so what time interval should it be bro ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you fire two requests, if the second request fires before the first request resolves, `xmlhttp.responseText` in your `onreadystatechange` listener would point to the `responseText` of the second (unresolved) request when the listener for the first request fires. This is because you only use a single global `xmlhttp` variable that is shared for all requests.

If you define `var xmlhttp` *inside* your `read_message`, instead of outside of it, then each new function call will have its own private `xmlhttp` variable:

```
function read_message() {
    var xmlhttp;
    //...
}
```

Comment: Any chance you can add code to stop/kill any previous unfinished calls?

Comment: I guess, i can, but how would be that bro ?

Comment: i updated my chat.txt file to 500KB approx and than saw response time in firefox it was 7K-10K where my refresh interval is 2K ... and div was not updated .. i think i will have to restrict content size ... and content beyond specific size will load with next call or something similar event..

Comment: thanks bro! i will do the rest... thanks for pointing out the stuff where i can debug further.. thanks once again :)